# How does one "autotag" in Visual Studio? (example: type "table" and have Visual Studio automatically convert this to "<table></table>"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I was watching a Pluralsight training video and the presenter was typing in "table" and then, presumably through some shortcut in Visual Studio, automatically converted this to `<table></table>`.

Through some experimentation, I found that I can type "table" and then hit the tab key (in Visual Studio 2015) and get this as a result automatically created for my by Visual Studio:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What I would like, however, is a more generic tagging shortcut, so I could use this technique with other types of elements too, like to turn "thead" into `<thead></thead>` and "span" into `<span></span>`, like the presenter was doing in the training video.

I have searched Google for a while, but am not even sure what to search for and haven't obtained any good results so far.

Anyone know more about these sort of Visual Studio shortcuts?

Comment: I figured it out: the presenter was using Resharper for the shortcuts.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out: the presenter was using Resharper for the shortcuts.